# Uncaught ReferenceError: calcDollar is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

[I've been getting undefined error and I dont know how to fix it.

Here's my code][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGWXc.png)

Comment: Please _never_ post images of your code; post code as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Typo in your code

The function you have defined in **js.js** file is **clacDollar**

And the function you are calling in **6.html** is **calcDollar**

Answer (score 0):

if you use calcDollar instead of clacDollar in your code  is better ..

try using

```
function calcDollar () {
```

in your definition